# Split Function with multiple digit numbers

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to separate out individual deal numbers that are provided in ranges when necessity occurs.  The deal numbers will be dynamic as the database grows so it is ineffective to use a static number of places.  The deal number format is either listed as E.G. "93246" or "93246-93249".  I only need one of the numbers from the range in order to verify other data.  Currently my code only captures the single digit just left of the -.  Any thoughts ideas?  This is a small piece of a much larger routine.

Thanks in advance

```
dealNum = reportsByFirm.Cells(row_counter, dealCol)
FileType = ".pdf"

If InStr(1, dealNum, "-") > 0 Then

    DealArray() = Split(dealNum, "-")
    tempDeal = LBound(DealArray)

ElseIf InStr(1, dealNum, "-") < 0 Then
    tempDeal = dealNum
End If

tradeLocation = tradesMaster.Columns(2).Find(What:=tempDeal)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line causes problem:

```
tempDeal = LBound(DealArray)
```

What it actually assigns to the `tempDeal` variable is the base index of array `DealArray` instead of its first element.

You need to change it like below:

```
tempDeal = DealArray(LBound(DealArray))
```

Comment: This works great!  Thank you very much!  Just started with VBA so the nuances get me.  So by using LBound(DealArray) as the Index location of Deal Array you call the first element rather than the base index?